# Can a Node.js application connect to bluetooth on Android?

Tags: android, node.js

Can a Node.js application connect to a bluetooth device on Android? If so, what do you think would be an efficient and stable way to do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This module should be helpful (I have never used it though):

https://github.com/eelcocramer/node-bluetooth-serial-port

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not.
I'm trying to do some experiment on these 2 techs myself on this too...
I'll update my answer later when I get some updates for you.

These looks promising though

- http://www.slideshare.net/Sudar/controlling-robots-using-javascript
- https://github.com/voodootikigod/node-serialport

though I was able to build bluetooth connectivity apps using JAVA + ANDROID with the link below

- http://homepages.ius.edu/RWISMAN/C490/html/Android-Bluetooth.htm
- See **IM Server (Java)** and P2P Instant Messaging (IM) on the link above

Comment: It's been a long time... but it has turned out the only way for us to get NodeJS running on Android is through an app called Termux. It like a small linux bash vm. Now our next wonder is will it be possible to connect to the bluetooth device from the Termux shell.